# Find which word is matched using to_tsquery in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

When using full text search in postgres is it possible to find which word was matched when using to_tsquery and an OR operator? I'm aware of the highlight method but this would require further logic to determine which field the highlighted word was in.

`WHERE  col_name @@ to_tsquery('word1 | word2'))`

Comment: There is nothing other than `ts_headline`, and that doesn't get you the matched word. That is an unusual requirement for full text search.

Comment: ok thanks, yeah I know it's a somewhat unique requirement, I will probably do it manually with multiple to_tsquery and hope the performance is ok

Comment: add `col_name @@ to_tsquery('word1') as matched_word1, col_name@@ to_tsquery('word2') as matched_word2` to your `select` list.